# How do I keep my range displayed following an input function?

Tags: python, loops, input, range

My code requires me to create a program that asks the user to enter a positive integer and then prints out all of the divisors of that number. So far, I have everything displayed the way I want outside of my range being displayed in the list like the output example. When I delete the input function that is directly below where my range should be displayed it does show. But when I keep the input function in, it only displays one number and seems to be taking a running total with my second if statement? I am bit lost, thank you all in advance!

CODE:

```
number = int(input('Enter number:'))
if number <= 0:
   print('Enter in a valid number!') 
   number = int(input('Enter number:'))

i=1
while i < 5:
    new_number = number*i
    i = i + 1
    print(new_number)
    another = str(input('Would you like to enter in another number (y/n)'))
if another == 'y': 
    number = int(input('Enter number:'))
    print(new_number)
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
Enter number:-20
Enter in a valid number!
Enter number:12
12
Would you like to enter in another number (y/n)y
Enter number:-20
12
-40
Would you like to enter in another number (y/n)
```

CORRECT OUTPUT:

```
Enter number: -20
    
    Enter in a valid number!
    Enter number: 12
    
    2
    3
    4
    6
    
    Would you like to enter in another number (y/n) y
    Enter number: 20
    
    2
    4
    5
    10
    
    Would you like to enter in another number (y/n) n
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is structured, you only calculate the divisors once. Also, your calculation of divisors doesn't work. If you consider the following code:

```
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter number: ')
    if user_input.isnumeric() and (number := int(user_input)) > 0:
        divisors = [i for i in range(1, number) if (number % i) == 0]
        for d in divisors:
            print(d)
    else:
        print(f'The value you entered ({user_input}) was invalid.')

    if input(f'Would you like to try again (y/n)? ').lower() == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

The entire code is within a loop `while True` so it will continue looping around forever until it reaches the `break`, so it keeps asking if you would like to try again.

The code for calculating the divisors is:

```
[i for i in range(1, number) if (number % i) == 0]
```

This is a list comprehension ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions%5D)) which iterates walks through numbers from 1 to the entered number; it then checks the remainder when dividing by that number is zero (i.e.  4 % 2 == 0 whereas 5 % 2 == 1).

Other things to look into is the walrus operator `:=` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)) which is used to avoid assign a value to the number on a single line.

Comment: why 2 divisions are used to check if a number is a valid divisor.  it can be done with a modulo division.  ... print([i for i in range(1, number) if number % i == 0]) ...

Comment: very true. i'll just change it. thanks.